# On a corollary of Kummer theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I faced this problem when I learn Kummer theorem :

> Let $p$ be a prime number and $m, n$ are two positive integer such that $p\nmid m$ and $p^k\mid n$ for some positive integer $k$. Prove that $p^k\mid \binom{n}{m}$.

I have tried to apply Kummer theorem but fails. I don't know how to do after writing the p-base representation of $n$, $n-m$ and $m$.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: As stated, the result is trivial: the conclusion appears among the assumptions. Do you have a typo?

Comment: The claim doesn't seem to make sense. Perhaps a typing mistake.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom nm=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}=\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot (n-(m-1))}{m!}$$

Now prove (this looks very similar to one of the usual proofs of Sylow theorem 1) that for some $\;1\le j\le m-1\;$ and for some $\;1\le r\le k\;$ we have:

$$p^r\mid j\iff p^r\mid(n-j)$$

because:

$$p^r\mid n\;\text{ so}:\;\begin{cases}p^r\mid j\implies p^r\mid(n-j)\\{}\\p^r\mid (n-j)\implies p^r\mid\left[n-(n-j)\right]\implies p^r\mid j\end{cases}$$

so all the powers of $\;p\;$ get cancelled in numerator and denominator of

$$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-m+1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(m-1)}$$

so we're left only with $\;\frac nm\;$, which is divisible by $\;p^k\;$ , and since the whole expression is an integer. we have finished.

Comment: Thank you very much for this proof. But I need a proof applying Kummer's theorem :)